# Can these two decreasing and concave functions intersect at more than two points?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both continuously differentiable in $x$ for $x\in[0,c]$.

We know both functions are decreasing and concave in $x$ anywhere on $[0,c]$.

I am curious if there is a way to show that if these two functions are to intersect, there can be a maximum of two points of intersection.

I did some plotting, and this seems to be true, but only for those functions I plotted, but I would like to show this is true in general or at least have a counter-example.

So far, I couldn't come up with two functions as a counter-example.

And for the proof, I don't know where to begin!

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: The classical example is $x^2$ and $x^2+\sin(x)$, which you can rescale and transform to fit your exact needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true.

$\textbf{Counterexample}.$ Consider functions $f(x)=-\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)^{1-x}$ (red curve) and $g(x)=-\log_{\frac{1}{16}}(1-x)$ (blue curve) on a segment $[0;0,9]$.

Equation $f(x)=g(x)$ has three roots (two obvious: $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{3}{4}$ and one more, which can find numerically $x\approx 0,63575$).[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Idea:** if we don't care about the condition "decreasing function" we may consider $-x^2$ and $-x^4$ on $[-1,1]$.

**Solution:**
Put $f(x) = -5x - x^2$ and $g(x) = -5x - x^4$ and consider $f(x-1)$ and $g(x-1)$ on $[0,2]$.